# How to add complex property EF Code First

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, code-first

I have three simple classes

```
public class Asset
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual Category {get;set;}
}

public class Category 
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
}

public class AssetCollection
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Asset> Assets {get;set;}

    ??????public bool HasAssetWithCategory(int ID)
    {
    ????????????
    }
}
```

I want to be able select from context HasAssetWithCategory like this

```
var assets = context.AssetCollections.Where(m => m.HasAssetWithCategory(SomeID));
```

I do not have clue even where to start.

Answer (score 0):

HasAssetCategory is a method that you have defined and cannot be converted to a SQL statement. So, EntityFramework cannot execute the query that you have. Instead, you should try this query,

```
var assets = context.AssetCollections.Where(m => m.Assets.Any(a => a.ID == someID));
```

Comment: So I cannot add this like property, but instead I need to write this in any place I must use it? :(

Comment: You can add a method for it on your context, or wrap the entire thing in a repository.

Comment: This question got me curious about implementing extension methods in EF. There's a somewhat related post on codereview about creating a generic helper method to generate POCOs for an entity - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3895/creating-extension-method-to-map-entity-with-subentities-object-to-poco-object. Read through some of the comments there as they might help you with this task, in particular passing `SomeID` to an instance of `MemberInitExpression` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301790.aspx. Practically speaking, I like to flatten my entities into view models.